# Android data binding with SQLite

Tags: android

I am trying to make a tutorial app with the help of Android, but I am confused where I should put the whole content (topic details). Actually I want to use it with the help of SQLite database. I used hashmap in my app.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to store your data on app, then SQL is best option. Otherwise you can use Remote server to store data. and SQLite for offline access to already viewed data.